# Directive name "SCGIMount" is not recognized

Tags: c, django, apache, https, ibm-midrange

I am trying to get a simple django app up on Http Server. The server is IBM Websphere Application Server. I have successfully compiled mod_scgi.c to the iseries. 
I proceeded to create a server and edit the configuration file with the following code:

```html
#Load the mod_scgi module
LoadModule scgi_module /qsys.lib/qgpl.lib/mod_scgi.srvpgm
# Set up location to be server by an SCGI server process
SCGIMount /dynamic 127.0.0.1:8080
```

This produces an error on the configuration file:  "Directive name "SCGIMount" is not recognized."

I am not sure how to proceed from here. Also, the mod_scgi.c file has been modified to allow it to be compiled to the iseries. I have provided the code below:

```html
/* mod_scgi.c
 *
 * Apache 2 implementation of the SCGI protocol.
 *
 */

#define MOD_SCGI_VERSION "1.14"
#define SCGI_PROTOCOL_VERSION "1"

#include "ap_config.h"
#include "apr_version.h"
#include "apr_lib.h"
#include "apr_strings.h"
#include "httpd.h"
#include "http_config.h"
#include "http_core.h"
#include "http_request.h"
#include "http_log.h"
#include "http_protocol.h"
#include "util_script.h"
#ifdef AS400
#include <strings.h>
#endif

#define DEFAULT_TIMEOUT  60 /* default socket timeout */

#define UNSET 0
#define ENABLED 1
#define DISABLED 2

#if APR_MAJOR_VERSION == 0
#define apr_socket_send apr_send
#define GET_PORT(port, addr) apr_sockaddr_port_get(&(port), addr)
#define CREATE_SOCKET(sock, family, pool) \
        apr_socket_create(sock, family, SOCK_STREAM, pool)
#else
#define GET_PORT(port, addr) ((port) = (addr)->port)
#define CREATE_SOCKET(sock, family, pool) \
        apr_socket_create(sock, family, SOCK_STREAM, APR_PROTO_TCP, pool)
#endif

typedef struct {
    char *path;
    char *addr;
    apr_port_t port;
} mount_entry;

/*
 * Configuration record.  Used per-directory configuration data.
 */
typedef struct {
    mount_entry mount;
    int enabled; /* mod_scgi is enabled from this directory */
    int timeout;
} scgi_cfg;

/* Server level configuration */
typedef struct {
    apr_array_header_t *mounts;
    int timeout;
} scgi_server_cfg;

/*
 * Declare ourselves so the configuration routines can find and know us.
 * We'll fill it in at the end of the module.
 */
module AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA scgi_module;

/*
 * Locate our directory configuration record for the current request.
 */
static scgi_cfg *
our_dconfig(request_rec *r)
{
    return (scgi_cfg *) ap_get_module_config(r->per_dir_config, &scgi_module);
}

static scgi_server_cfg *our_sconfig(server_rec *s)
{
    return (scgi_server_cfg *) ap_get_module_config(s->module_config,
                                                    &scgi_module);
}

static int
mount_entry_matches(const char *url, const char *prefix,
                    const char **path_info)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; prefix[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (url[i] == '\0' || url[i] != prefix[i])
            return 0;
    }
    if (url[i] == '\0' || url[i] == '/') {
        *path_info = url + i;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

static int scgi_translate(request_rec *r)
{
    scgi_cfg *cfg = our_dconfig(r);

    if (cfg->enabled == DISABLED) {
        return DECLINED;
    }

    if (cfg->mount.addr != UNSET) {
        ap_assert(cfg->mount.port != UNSET);
        r->handler = "scgi-handler";
        r->filename = r->uri;
        return OK;
    }
    else {
        int i;
        scgi_server_cfg *scfg = our_sconfig(r->server);
        mount_entry *entries = (mount_entry *) scfg->mounts->elts;
        for (i = 0; i < scfg->mounts->nelts; ++i) {
            const char *path_info;
            mount_entry *mount = &entries[i];
            if (mount_entry_matches(r->uri, mount->path, &path_info)) {
                r->handler = "scgi-handler";
                r->path_info = apr_pstrdup(r->pool, path_info);
                r->filename = r->uri;
                ap_set_module_config(r->request_config, &scgi_module, mount);
                return OK;
            }
        }
    }
    return DECLINED;
}

static int scgi_map_location(request_rec *r)
{
    if (r->handler && strcmp(r->handler, "scgi-handler") == 0) {
        return OK; /* We don't want directory walk. */
    }
    return DECLINED;
}

static void log_err(const char *file, int line, request_rec *r,
                    apr_status_t status, const char *msg)
{
    ap_log_rerror(file, line, APLOG_ERR, status, r, "scgi: %s", msg);
}

static void log_debug(const char *file, int line, request_rec *r, const
                      char *msg)
{
    ap_log_rerror(file, line, APLOG_DEBUG, APR_SUCCESS, r, msg);
}

static char *http2env(apr_pool_t *p, const char *name)
{
    char *env_name = apr_pstrcat(p, "HTTP_", name, NULL);
    char *cp;
    
    for (cp = env_name + 5; *cp != 0; cp++) {
        if (*cp == '-') {
            *cp = '_';
        }
        else {
            *cp = apr_toupper(*cp);
        }
    }

    return env_name;
}

static char *lookup_name(apr_table_t *t, const char *name)
{
    const apr_array_header_t *hdrs_arr = apr_table_elts(t);
    apr_table_entry_t *hdrs = (apr_table_entry_t *) hdrs_arr->elts;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < hdrs_arr->nelts; ++i) {
        if (hdrs[i].key == NULL)
            continue;

        if (strcasecmp(hdrs[i].key, name) == 0)
            return hdrs[i].val;
    }
    return NULL;
}


static char *lookup_header(request_rec *r, const char *name)
{
    return lookup_name(r->headers_in, name);
}


static void add_header(apr_table_t *t, const char *name, const char *value)
{
    if (name != NULL && value != NULL)
        apr_table_addn(t, name, value);
}

static int find_path_info(const char *uri, const char *path_info)
{
    int n;
    n = strlen(uri) - strlen(path_info);
    ap_assert(n >= 0);
    return n;
}

/* This code is a duplicate of what's in util_script.c.  We can't use
 * r->unparsed_uri because it gets changed if there was a redirect. */
static char *original_uri(request_rec *r)
{
    char *first, *last;

    if (r->the_request == NULL) {
        return (char *) apr_pcalloc(r->pool, 1);
    }

    first = r->the_request; /* use the request-line */

    while (*first && !apr_isspace(*first)) {
        ++first;            /* skip over the method */
    }
    while (apr_isspace(*first)) {
        ++first;            /*   and the space(s)   */
    }

    last = first;
    while (*last && !apr_isspace(*last)) {
        ++last;             /* end at next whitespace */
    }

    return apr_pstrmemdup(r->pool, first, last - first);
}

/* buffered socket implementation (buckets are overkill) */

#define BUFFER_SIZE 8000

struct sockbuff {
    apr_socket_t *sock;
    char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int used;
};

static void binit(struct sockbuff *s, apr_socket_t *sock)
{
    s->sock = sock;
    s->used = 0;
}

static apr_status_t sendall(apr_socket_t *sock, char *buf, apr_size_t len)
{
    apr_status_t rv;
    apr_size_t n;
    while (len > 0) {
        n = len;
        if ((rv = apr_socket_send(sock, buf, &n))) return rv;
        buf += n;
        len -= n;
    }
    return APR_SUCCESS;
}

static apr_status_t bflush(struct sockbuff *s)
{
    apr_status_t rv;
    ap_assert(s->used >= 0 && s->used <= BUFFER_SIZE);
    if (s->used) {
            if ((rv = sendall(s->sock, s->buf, s->used))) return rv;
            s->used = 0;
    }
    return APR_SUCCESS;
}

static apr_status_t bwrite(struct sockbuff *s, char *buf, apr_size_t len)
{
    apr_status_t rv;
    if (len >= BUFFER_SIZE - s->used) {
        if ((rv = bflush(s))) return rv;
        while (len >= BUFFER_SIZE) {
            if ((rv = sendall(s->sock, buf, BUFFER_SIZE))) return rv;
            buf += BUFFER_SIZE;
            len -= BUFFER_SIZE;
        }
    }
    if (len > 0) {
        ap_assert(len < BUFFER_SIZE - s->used);
        memcpy(s->buf + s->used, buf, len);
        s->used += len;
    }
    return APR_SUCCESS;
}

static apr_status_t bputs(struct sockbuff *s, char *buf)
{
    return bwrite(s, buf, strlen(buf));
}

static apr_status_t bputc(struct sockbuff *s, char c)
{
    char buf[1];
    buf[0] = c;
    return bwrite(s, buf, 1);
}


static apr_status_t
send_headers(request_rec *r, struct sockbuff *s)
{
    /* headers to send */
    apr_table_t *t;
    const apr_array_header_t *hdrs_arr, *env_arr;
    apr_table_entry_t *hdrs, *env;
    unsigned long int n = 0;
    char *buf;
    int i;
    apr_status_t rv = 0;
    apr_port_t  port = 0;
    GET_PORT(port, r->connection->remote_addr);

    log_debug(APLOG_MARK,r, "sending headers");
    t = apr_table_make(r->pool, 40);
    if (!t)
        return APR_ENOMEM;
    /* CONTENT_LENGTH must come first and always be present */
    buf = lookup_header(r, "Content-Length");
    if (buf == NULL)
        buf = "0";
    add_header(t, "CONTENT_LENGTH",  buf);
    add_header(t, "SCGI", SCGI_PROTOCOL_VERSION);
    add_header(t, "SERVER_SOFTWARE", ap_get_server_version());
    add_header(t, "SERVER_PROTOCOL", r->protocol);
    add_header(t, "SERVER_NAME", ap_get_server_name(r));
    add_header(t, "SERVER_ADMIN", r->server->server_admin);
    add_header(t, "SERVER_ADDR", r->connection->local_ip);
    add_header(t, "SERVER_PORT", apr_psprintf(r->pool, "%u",
                                              ap_get_server_port(r)));
    add_header(t, "REMOTE_ADDR", r->connection->remote_ip);
    add_header(t, "REMOTE_PORT", apr_psprintf(r->pool, "%d", port));
    add_header(t, "REMOTE_USER", r->user);
    add_header(t, "REQUEST_METHOD", r->method);
    add_header(t, "REQUEST_URI", original_uri(r));
    add_header(t, "QUERY_STRING", r->args ? r->args : "");
    if (r->path_info) {
        int path_info_start = find_path_info(r->uri, r->path_info);
        add_header(t, "SCRIPT_NAME", apr_pstrndup(r->pool, r->uri,
                                                  path_info_start));
        add_header(t, "PATH_INFO", r->path_info);
    }
    else {
        /* skip PATH_INFO, don't know it */
        add_header(t, "SCRIPT_NAME", r->uri);
    }
    add_header(t, "CONTENT_TYPE", lookup_header(r, "Content-type"));
    add_header(t, "DOCUMENT_ROOT", ap_document_root(r));

    /* HTTP headers */
    hdrs_arr = apr_table_elts(r->headers_in);
    hdrs = (apr_table_entry_t *) hdrs_arr->elts;
    for (i = 0; i < hdrs_arr->nelts; ++i) {
        if (hdrs[i].key) {
            add_header(t, http2env(r->pool, hdrs[i].key), hdrs[i].val);
        }
    }

    /* environment variables */
    env_arr = apr_table_elts(r->subprocess_env);
    env = (apr_table_entry_t*) env_arr->elts;
    for (i = 0; i < env_arr->nelts; ++i) {
        add_header(t, env[i].key, env[i].val);
    }

    hdrs_arr = apr_table_elts(t);
    hdrs = (apr_table_entry_t*) hdrs_arr->elts;

    /* calculate length of header data (including nulls) */
    for (i = 0; i < hdrs_arr->nelts; ++i) {
        n += strlen(hdrs[i].key) + 1;
        n += strlen(hdrs[i].val) + 1;
    }

    buf = apr_psprintf(r->pool, "%lu:", n);
    if (!buf)
        return APR_ENOMEM;
    rv = bputs(s, buf);
    if (rv)
        return rv;

    for (i = 0; i < hdrs_arr->nelts; ++i) {
        rv = bputs(s, hdrs[i].key);
        if (rv) return rv;
        rv = bputc(s, '\0');
        if (rv) return rv;
        rv = bputs(s, hdrs[i].val);
        if (rv) return rv;
        rv = bputc(s, '\0');
        if (rv) return rv;
    }

    rv = bputc(s, ',');
    if (rv)
        return rv;

    return APR_SUCCESS;
}

static apr_status_t send_request_body(request_rec *r, struct sockbuff *s)
{
    if (ap_should_client_block(r)) {
        char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];
        apr_status_t rv;
        apr_off_t len;

        while ((len = ap_get_client_block(r, buf, sizeof buf)) > 0) {
            if ((rv = bwrite(s, buf, len))) return rv;
        }
        if (len == -1)
            return HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR; /* what to return? */
    }
    return APR_SUCCESS;
}

#define CONFIG_VALUE(value, fallback) ((value) != UNSET ? (value) : (fallback))

static apr_status_t
open_socket(apr_socket_t **sock, request_rec *r)
{
    int timeout;
    int retries = 4;
    int sleeptime = 1;
    apr_status_t rv;
    apr_sockaddr_t *sockaddr;
    scgi_server_cfg *scfg = our_sconfig(r->server);
    scgi_cfg *cfg = our_dconfig(r);
    mount_entry *m = (mount_entry *) ap_get_module_config(r->request_config,
                                                          &scgi_module);
    if (!m) {
        m = &cfg->mount;
    }

    timeout = CONFIG_VALUE(cfg->timeout, CONFIG_VALUE(scfg->timeout,
                                                      DEFAULT_TIMEOUT));
    rv = apr_sockaddr_info_get(&sockaddr,
                               CONFIG_VALUE(m->addr, "localhost"),
                               APR_UNSPEC,
                               CONFIG_VALUE(m->port, 4000),
                               0,
                               r->pool);
    if (rv) {
        log_err(APLOG_MARK, r, rv, "apr_sockaddr_info_get() error");
        return rv;
    }

 restart:
    *sock = NULL;
    rv = CREATE_SOCKET(sock, sockaddr->family, r->pool);
    if (rv) {
        log_err(APLOG_MARK, r, rv, "apr_socket_create() error");
        return rv;
    }

    rv = apr_socket_timeout_set(*sock, apr_time_from_sec(timeout));
    if (rv) {
        log_err(APLOG_MARK, r, rv, "apr_socket_timeout_set() error");
        return rv;
    }

    rv = apr_socket_connect(*sock, sockaddr);
    if (rv) {
        apr_socket_close(*sock);
        if ((APR_STATUS_IS_ECONNREFUSED(rv) |
            APR_STATUS_IS_EINPROGRESS(rv)) && retries > 0) {
            /* server may be temporarily down, retry */
            ap_log_rerror(APLOG_MARK, APLOG_NOERRNO|APLOG_DEBUG, rv, r,
                          "scgi: connection failed, retrying");
            apr_sleep(apr_time_from_sec(sleeptime));
            --retries;
            sleeptime *= 2;
            goto restart;
        }
        log_err(APLOG_MARK, r, rv, "scgi: can't connect to server");
        return rv;
    }

#ifdef APR_TCP_NODELAY
    /* disable Nagle, we don't send small packets */
    apr_socket_opt_set(*sock, APR_TCP_NODELAY, 1);
#endif

    return APR_SUCCESS;
}

#ifdef AS400
static int getsfunc_BRIGADE(char *buf, int len, void *arg)
{
    apr_bucket_brigade *bb = (apr_bucket_brigade *)arg;
    const char *dst_end = buf + len - 1; /* leave room for terminating null */
    char *dst = buf;
    apr_bucket *e = APR_BRIGADE_FIRST(bb);
    apr_status_t rv;
    int done = 0;

    while ((dst < dst_end) && !done && e != APR_BRIGADE_SENTINEL(bb)
           && !APR_BUCKET_IS_EOS(e)) {
        const char *bucket_data;
        apr_size_t bucket_data_len;
        const char *src;
        const char *src_end;
        apr_bucket * next;

        rv = apr_bucket_read(e, &bucket_data, &bucket_data_len,
                             APR_BLOCK_READ);
        if (rv != APR_SUCCESS || (bucket_data_len == 0)) {
            *dst = '\0';
            return APR_STATUS_IS_TIMEUP(rv) ? -1 : 0;
        }
        src = bucket_data;
        src_end = bucket_data + bucket_data_len;
        while ((src < src_end) && (dst < dst_end) && !done) {
            if (*src == '\n') {
                done = 1;
            }
            else if (*src != '\r') {
                *dst++ = *src;
            }
            src++;
        }

        if (src < src_end) {
            apr_bucket_split(e, src - bucket_data);
        }
        next = APR_BUCKET_NEXT(e);
        APR_BUCKET_REMOVE(e);
        apr_bucket_destroy(e);
        e = next;
    }
    *dst = 0;
    return done;
}
#endif

static int scgi_handler(request_rec *r)
{
    apr_status_t rv = 0;
    int http_status = 0;
    struct sockbuff s;
    apr_socket_t *sock;
    apr_bucket_brigade *bb = NULL;
    apr_bucket *b          = NULL;
    const char *location;

    if (strcmp(r->handler, "scgi-handler"))
        return DECLINED;

    http_status = ap_setup_client_block(r, REQUEST_CHUNKED_ERROR);
    if (http_status != OK)
        return http_status;

    log_debug(APLOG_MARK, r, "connecting to server");

    rv = open_socket(&sock, r);
    if (rv) {
        return HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    }

    binit(&s, sock);

    rv = send_headers(r, &s);
    if (rv) {
        log_err(APLOG_MARK, r, rv, "error sending request headers");
        return HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    }

    rv = send_request_body(r, &s);
    if (rv) {
        log_err(APLOG_MARK, r, rv, "error sending request body");
        return HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    }

    rv = bflush(&s);
    if (rv) {
        log_err(APLOG_MARK, r, rv, "error sending request");
        return HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    }

    log_debug(APLOG_MARK, r, "reading response headers");
    bb = apr_brigade_create(r->connection->pool, r->connection->bucket_alloc);
    b = apr_bucket_socket_create(sock, r->connection->bucket_alloc);
    APR_BRIGADE_INSERT_TAIL(bb, b);
    b = apr_bucket_eos_create(r->connection->bucket_alloc);
    APR_BRIGADE_INSERT_TAIL(bb, b);

#ifdef AS400    
    rv = ap_scan_script_header_err_core(r, NULL, getsfunc_BRIGADE, bb);
#else
    rv = ap_scan_script_header_err_brigade(r, bb, NULL);
#endif
    if (rv) {
        if (rv == HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR) {
            log_err(APLOG_MARK, r, rv, "error reading response headers");
        }
        else {
            /* Work around an Apache bug whereby the returned status is
             * ignored and status_line is used instead.  This bug is
             * present at least in 2.0.54.
             */
            r->status_line = NULL;
        }
        apr_brigade_destroy(bb);
        return rv;
    }

    location = apr_table_get(r->headers_out, "Location");

    if (location && location[0] == '/' &&
        ((r->status == HTTP_OK) || ap_is_HTTP_REDIRECT(r->status))) {

        apr_brigade_destroy(bb);

        /* Internal redirect -- fake-up a pseudo-request */
        r->status = HTTP_OK;

        /* This redirect needs to be a GET no matter what the original
         * method was.
         */
        r->method = apr_pstrdup(r->pool, "GET");
        r->method_number = M_GET;

        /* We already read the message body (if any), so don't allow
         * the redirected request to think it has one. We can ignore
         * Transfer-Encoding, since we used REQUEST_CHUNKED_ERROR.
         */
        apr_table_unset(r->headers_in, "Content-Length");

        ap_internal_redirect_handler(location, r);
        return OK;
    }

    rv = ap_pass_brigade(r->output_filters, bb);
    if (rv) {
        log_err(APLOG_MARK, r, rv, "ap_pass_brigade()");
        return HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    }

    return OK;
}


static int scgi_init(apr_pool_t *p, apr_pool_t *plog, apr_pool_t *ptemp,
                       server_rec *base_server)
{
    ap_add_version_component(p, "mod_scgi/" MOD_SCGI_VERSION);
    return OK;
}


static void *
create_dir_config(apr_pool_t *p, char *dirspec)
{
    scgi_cfg *cfg = apr_pcalloc(p, sizeof(scgi_cfg));

    cfg->enabled = UNSET;
    cfg->mount.addr = UNSET;
    cfg->mount.port = UNSET;
    cfg->timeout = UNSET;

    return cfg;
}

#define MERGE(b, n, a) (n->a == UNSET ? b->a : n->a)

static void *
merge_dir_config(apr_pool_t *p, void *basev, void *newv)
{
    scgi_cfg* cfg = apr_pcalloc(p, sizeof(scgi_cfg));
    scgi_cfg* base = basev;
    scgi_cfg* new = newv;

    cfg->enabled = MERGE(base, new, enabled);
    cfg->mount.addr = MERGE(base, new, mount.addr);
    cfg->mount.port = MERGE(base, new, mount.port);
    cfg->timeout = MERGE(base, new, timeout);

    return cfg;
}

static void *
create_server_config(apr_pool_t *p, server_rec *s)
{
    scgi_server_cfg *c =
        (scgi_server_cfg *) apr_pcalloc(p, sizeof(scgi_server_cfg));

    c->mounts = apr_array_make(p, 20, sizeof(mount_entry));
        c->timeout = UNSET;
    return c;
}

static void *
merge_server_config(apr_pool_t *p, void *basev, void *overridesv)
{
    scgi_server_cfg *c = (scgi_server_cfg *)
        apr_pcalloc(p, sizeof(scgi_server_cfg));
    scgi_server_cfg *base = (scgi_server_cfg *) basev;
    scgi_server_cfg *overrides = (scgi_server_cfg *) overridesv;

    c->mounts = apr_array_append(p, overrides->mounts, base->mounts);
        c->timeout = MERGE(base, overrides, timeout);
    return c;
}

static const char *
cmd_mount(cmd_parms *cmd, void *dummy, const char *path, const char *addr)
{
    int n;
    apr_status_t rv;
    char *scope_id = NULL; /* A ip6 parameter - not used here. */
    scgi_server_cfg *scfg = our_sconfig(cmd->server);
    mount_entry *new = apr_array_push(scfg->mounts);
    n = strlen(path);
    while (n > 0 && path[n-1] == '/') {
        n--; /* strip trailing slashes */
    }
    new->path = apr_pstrndup(cmd->pool, path, n);
    rv = apr_parse_addr_port(&new->addr, &scope_id, &new->port, addr,
                             cmd->pool);
    if (rv)
        return "error parsing address:port string";
    return NULL;
}

static const char *
cmd_server(cmd_parms *cmd, void *pcfg, const char *addr_and_port)
{
    apr_status_t rv;
    scgi_cfg *cfg = pcfg;
    char *scope_id = NULL; /* A ip6 parameter - not used here. */

    if (cmd->path == NULL)
        return "not a server command";

    rv = apr_parse_addr_port(&cfg->mount.addr, &scope_id, &cfg->mount.port,
                             addr_and_port, cmd->pool);
    if (rv)
        return "error parsing address:port string";

    return NULL;
}


static const char *
cmd_handler(cmd_parms* cmd, void* pcfg, int flag)
{
    scgi_cfg *cfg = pcfg;

    if (cmd->path == NULL) /* server command */
        return "not a server command";

    if (flag)
        cfg->enabled = ENABLED;
    else
        cfg->enabled = DISABLED;

    return NULL;
}


static const char *
cmd_timeout(cmd_parms *cmd, void* pcfg, const char *strtimeout)
{
    scgi_cfg *dcfg = pcfg;
    int timeout = atoi(strtimeout);

    if (cmd->path == NULL) {
        scgi_server_cfg *scfg = our_sconfig(cmd->server);
        scfg->timeout = timeout;
    }
    else {
        dcfg->timeout = timeout;
    }

    return NULL;
}

static const command_rec scgi_cmds[] =
{
    AP_INIT_TAKE2("SCGIMount", cmd_mount, NULL, RSRC_CONF,
                  "path prefix and address of SCGI server"),
    AP_INIT_TAKE1("SCGIServer", cmd_server, NULL, ACCESS_CONF,
                  "Address and port of an SCGI server (e.g. localhost:4000)"),
    AP_INIT_FLAG( "SCGIHandler", cmd_handler, NULL, ACCESS_CONF,
                  "On or Off to enable or disable the SCGI handler"),
    AP_INIT_TAKE1("SCGIServerTimeout", cmd_timeout, NULL, ACCESS_CONF|RSRC_CONF,
                  "Timeout (in seconds) for communication with the SCGI server."),
    {NULL}
};


static void scgi_register_hooks(apr_pool_t *p)
{
    ap_hook_post_config(scgi_init, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_MIDDLE);
    ap_hook_handler(scgi_handler, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_MIDDLE);
    ap_hook_translate_name(scgi_translate, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_LAST);
    ap_hook_map_to_storage(scgi_map_location, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_FIRST);
}


/* Dispatch list for API hooks */
module AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA scgi_module = {
    STANDARD20_MODULE_STUFF,
    create_dir_config,             /* create per-dir config structs */
    merge_dir_config,              /* merge per-dir config structs */
    create_server_config,          /* create per-server config structs */
    merge_server_config,           /* merge per-server config structs */
    scgi_cmds,                     /* table of config file commands */
    scgi_register_hooks,           /* register hooks */
};
```

UPDATE to the UPDATE:

I have narrowed down the problem to the following Error Message MCH3601:

```html
 MCH3601    Escape                  40   06/05/15  15:41:10.884937  MOD_SCGI     QGPL        *STMT    MOD_SCGI    QGPL        *STMT 
                                      From module . . . . . . . . :   MOD_SCGI                                                      
                                      From procedure  . . . . . . :   our_dconfig                                                   
                                      Statement . . . . . . . . . :   1                                                             
                                      To module . . . . . . . . . :   MOD_SCGI                                                      
                                      To procedure  . . . . . . . :   our_dconfig                                                   
                                      Statement . . . . . . . . . :   1                                                             
                                      Thread  . . . . :   00000039                                                                  
                                      Message . . . . :   Pointer not set for location referenced.                                  
                                      Cause . . . . . :   A pointer was used, either directly or as a basing                        
                                        pointer, that has not been set to an address.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the web server is actually Apache, not WAS.  What does the Apache log say?

Is the Apache user profile authorised to the mod_scgi service program, and to the library QGPL?

Comment: Yes, QTMHHTP1 is authorized for that library

Comment: The reason I'm looking at authorities is because SCGIMount isn't a standard Apache directive. Until mod_scgi loads, it will be considered an error.  Check the Apache log to see if there is any more useful information beyond the job log.  Is QTMHHTP1 authorised to the service program?  The only LoadModule I have is for Zend and it's all in upper case: LoadModule zend_enabler_module /QSYS.LIB/QHTTPSVR.LIB/QZFAST.SRVPGM  Maybe that is an issue?  In my case, *PUBLIC has *USE on library QHTTPSVR and to the QZFAST service program.

Comment: I have looked the log file and the authorities. It seems to be another error. I have new update above and the seems to be a pointer

Comment: One of the requests to our_dconfig seems to have a null request_rec.  Maybe you can sprinkle some dump / logger statements and figure out which one, and why.